# The method to obtain the probability from the mgf

Tags: probability, random-variables, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables where the moment generating function mgf are

$M_X(t) = e^{2(e^t -1)}$ and $M_Y(t) = \big( \frac{3e^t +1}{4}\big)^{10}$

what is the value of $P(X + Y = 2)$ and $E(XY)$ ?

For $E(XY) = E(X)~E(Y) $ since they are independent then $E(X) = M^{'}_X(0)$ so $$ E(XY) = E(X)~E(Y) = \big(2e^{0+e^0-2} \times \frac{15 e^0(3e^0+1)^9}{524288} \big)   $$

For $P(X+Y = 2)$, I know that $P(X+Y=2) = P(X=0)P(Y=2)+P(X=1)P(Y=1)+P(X=2)P(Y=0)$ but I have a difficulty to continue! i.e to get the probabilities from the mgf, we need to use the inverse Laplace transform, but I have a difficulty to compute the integral $$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma - iT}^{\gamma + iT} e^{zx} E(e^{tZ})dz$$ any help plz

Comment: Do you have to invert by contour integration or can you invert by inspection? Because in this situation you can basically read off what the distributions of X and Y are just by knowing common MGFs. Contour integration will work, but still.

Comment: @Ian do you mean by inspection to say that $X$ is a Poisson and $Y$ is a Binomial ? No, I would like to learn how to prove this using the integral

Comment: we know that $X$ is poisson and $Y$ is binomial by matching the MGFs with known MGFs.